# BigCommerce API request 500 server error

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a php application using the BigCommerce PHP APi v 3.0, the application sends multiple API request to get some data on the store orders (it's a private application in BC), my problem is that of late more and more request are failing and my application is returning a 500 server error because of it. The behaviour is very odd because at times it works and at others it returns that error... Can anyone help me with this, has this happen to more ppl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question here, here's what i got as a response from BigCommerce support:

> Thank you for contacting Bigcommerce and for your report.
>
> The 500 errors you have been seeing in greater number this week last
>   week are expected as there have been several server performance
>   issues. A couple due to DDoS attacks, some relating to our object
>   storage system, and issues with our webhooks queue that specifically
>   affected the API proxy. We are sorry about these service interruptions
>   and know that our Technical Operations team and been working hard to
>   first correct then look to prevent the root issues. Assuming no new
>   issues crop up we should see a reduction in 500 errors back to more
>   expected, much less frequent levels.
>
> We do appreciate your feedback on this and for bearing with us while
>   we work to get things back to normal operating levels. While 500
>   errors are something that can occur they should not be as frequent as
>   they have likely been seen this week.